# ¿Por qué el error TypeInitializationException?

Tags: c#

estoy ejecutando un app, pero me sale un error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo creo que es por esta linea de codigo:

```
static CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre =
          new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
```

me sale el mensaje: Se produjo una excepción en el iniciador de tipo de 'WinFormSpeesh.Form1"

y apunta a : "Application.Run(new form1());

me sale este mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Configura la solución en Debug, coloca un punto de interrupción en esa línea y corre el programa. Luego con F11 vas línea por línea hasta donde salta el problema (que debería estar en alguna línea del `InitializeComponent()` en `Form1.Designer.cs`.  
Luego que sepas dónde salta el error actualiza la pregunta y comentá qué te dió el error.

Comment: Como el detalle dice, "No recognizer of the required ID found.  Nombre del parametro: culture".  Parece que no logra encontrar en tu computadora la librería del speech recognition en inglés. Tal vez no lo tienes instalado.  Te sugiero hacer una búsqueda por ese mensaje de error. Varios han tenido el mismo problema.  En particular, puede que [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281858/speechrecognitionengine-recognizers) te ayude.  Cuando lo resuelvas, considera agregar una respuesta a tu pregunta para que otros se beneficien.

Comment: nada aun :( ya intente